# Python Pyrogram download_media doesn't work

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I have a simple function to download images from Telegram messages by using Pyrogram, but the `download_media` method doesn't download anything for me, and the returned file_path is always None. The received `message` object and its `photo` attribute do have some data in them, but still, the download won't work for me. I tried passing `message`, `m_photo` and `file_id` to `download_media` to no avail.

```
async def download_photo(message):
    m_photo = message.photo
    file_id = m_photo.file_id
    file_unique_id = m_photo.file_unique_id
    width = m_photo.width
    height = m_photo.height
    file_size = m_photo.file_size
    date = m_photo.date

    print(m_photo)  
    print(f"Photo details - File ID: {file_id}, File Unique ID: {file_unique_id}, Width: {width}, Height: {height}, File Size: {file_size}, Date: {date}")

    file_path = await app.download_media(m_photo, file_name=f'{message.chat.id}_{file_unique_id}.jpg')

    return file_path

asyncio.run(download_photo(message))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your pyrogram client in the group or channel from where you want to download? If this is not the case, I think you should try it that way, something that would resolve the conflict is to try with filters

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34830874)

Answer (score 0):

download_media() often has FloodWait exception hidden by pyrogram library.

You could

1. add logging and check for FloodWait and other exceptions
2. go to pyrogram github/issues and search by "FloodWait" then apple some patches to your current installation